# Chrome Timeline View Modes

Tags: performance, google-chrome, web, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to do this tutorial on using the timeline: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/demos/too-much-layout

Unfortunately when I go to the timeline in Chrome I am not seeing the view mode options "Events", "Frames" and "Memory". I've read other tutorials and they all seem to show these view modes but for the life of me I cannot figure out how to see them. This is what I see: http://imgur.com/33XEfJ5

Please note that this is not an issue with my version of Chrome. I actually was able to see the view modes when I hooked up my phone and ran the inspector through chrome://inspect. But I need to be able to see them when on my laptop as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the new version the UI was slightly changed.

You can flip overview to frame mode by clicking a small button with vertical bars at the top.
Also memory mode might be enabled by checking Memory checkbox.